# Meteor._wrapAsync causes 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, redis, node-redis

An app is using `meteor-redis` package to run a redis query which can sometimes take 30 seconds to return 100k results. During this waiting time, Meteor freezes and takes up 100% CPU while waiting for the query results.

```
var client = redis.createClient(port, url)
client.zrangebyscoreSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(client.zrangebyscore)

client.zrangebyscoreSync(['game:scores', '', '+inf'], function(err, scores) {

    _.each(scores, function(score, player) {
        var doc = { ... }
        Scores.insert(doc)
    })


})
```

**Question:** Is there anyway to let Meteor do something else while waiting for redis to return the huge dataset? If `client.zrangebyscore` is not wrapped with `Meteor._wrapAsync`, Meteor would throw the error

```
 Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
```

and the trace points it to the line `Scores.insert(doc)`.

Comment: Since you are trying to use Redis, I wonder if you would be interested in the Meteor-Redis integration I am working on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/Jl5Jt739wdA

Answer (score 0):

In general Meteor will allow other methods to run, provided you run `this.unblock()` on them first, thus spinning those requests into new fibers.

The reason you get 100% CPU usage is probably a combination of the sort of cpu idling fibers does and the task being performed underneath.

If this is an issue, you could try using Meteor.bindEnvironment instead, which won't use future's to wait, and still use callbacks to ensure that everything remains unblocked:

```
client.zrangebyscore(['game:scores', '', '+inf'], Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result) {
    _.each(scores, function(score, player) {
        var doc = { ... }
        Scores.insert(doc)
    })
}));
```

Meteor bindEnvironment is almost the same thing as Meteor._wrapAsync, except it's missing the pieces that wait for a result. It looks like you're not using this bit though since you don't look for results coming out of `client.zrangebyscoreSync`. Meteor.bindEnvironment might be better for this use, it wraps your callbacks in a Fiber, so you can use Meteor code in them.

Comment: `scores` returned by `client.zrangebyscsore` is being used by `_.each`. Can we still use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx it should be fine. I'm a bit unsure on what exactly breaks you out of the fiber (besides setTimeout), I think its using native node methods like request and fs and stuff. If its anything like `forEach` it should be fine. Update - just checked its source, it should be fine because it uses `.call` to bind the callback or uses `forEach` under the hood anyway.